A simpler way for proving $4^{2n+1} + 7^{2n+1}$ is divisible by $11$?
Does my induction step seem correct?
My logic is to split up this step into two parts and then bring them together to prove its divisible by $11$. It does seem very messy and I'm wondering if there is a smoother way to write this.
Prove that $4^{2n+1} + 7^{2n+1}$ is divisible by $11$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Base Case:

$4^{2(1)+1} + 7^{2(1)+1} = 4^3 + 7^3$ = 407. Divided by 11 is $37$

Inductive Step: Assume that for some arbitrary $k$, the equation is divisible by $11$.
$4^{2(k+1)+1} + 7^{2(k+1)+1} = 4^{2k+3} + 7^{2k+3}$
We can express $4^{2k+3}$ and $7^{2k+3}$ separately as:

$4^{2k+3} = 4^3 \times 4^{2k} = 64 \times 4^{2k}$
$7^{2k+3} = 7^3 \times 7^{2k} = 343 \times 7^{2k}$

And then when we combine them together:
$4^{2(k+1)+1} + 7^{2(k+1)+1} = 64 \times 4^{2k} + 343 \times 7^{2k}$
Which after applying dividing 11 -- which is possible since its a product of 11 -- leads to
$11 \times (6 \times 4^{2k} + 31 \times 7^{2k})$
By mathematical induction, the statement is true :)

I don't understand how did you divide by $11$ at the end. None of $64$ and $343$ are divisible by $11$. The idea is to use the induction hypothesis, so you should write your expression as something that involves $4^{2k+1}+7^{2k+1}$, not $4^{2k}+7^{2k}$.

$64 \ne 11\times 6$ and $343 \ne 11\times 31$.  And why are you trying to go back to $4^{2k}+7^{2k}$.  Your assumption is about $4^{2k \color{red}{+1}} + 7^{2k \color{red}{+1}}$.  That is divisible by $11$ but you don't know diddly squat about $4^{2k} + 7^{2k}$.  Note $4^{2k + 3} + 7^{2k+3} = 16\times 4^{2k+1} + 49\times 7^{2k+1}$.... which doesn't look promising until you notice !!!!HOLY FISHSTICKS!!! $49 - 16=33$!!!!!!

$11 \times (6\times 4^{2k} + 31\times 7^{2k})= 66\times 4^{2k} + 341\times 7^{2k} = 64\times 4^{2k} + 343 \times 7^{2k} + (2\times 4^{2k} - 2\times 7^{2k}$.  Now you need to prove that $2\times 4^{2k} - 2\times 7^{2k}$ is divisible by $11$.  Which you can do, but you have not set yourself up for the task.

Hah!  A completely off-tangent outside the box way to do it!  Without induction.  Let $m =n-1$ then $4^{2n+1} + 7^{2n+1}=4^{2m+3} + 7^{2m+3}=64\cdot4^{2m}+343\cdot7^{2m}=11(6\cdot 4^{2m}+31\cdot7^{2m})+2(4^{2m}-7^{2m)}$. Now $4^{2m}-7^{2m}=(4+7)(4^{2m-1}-4^{2m-2}7+4^{2m-3}7^2-.... +4\cdot7^{2m-2}-7^{2m-2})$.  And as $4+7=11$ we are done: $4^{2n+1}+7^{2n+1}=11[(6\cdot 4^{2m}+31\cdot7^{2m})+ 2(4^{2m-1}-4^{2m-2}7+4^{2m-3}7^2-.... +4\cdot7^{2m-2}-7^{2m-2})]$... assuming $n\ge 2$ ... However, I do not recommend you show this to your instructor.

BTW.  You can use $n=0$ as your base case.  $4^{2\cdot 0 + 1} + 7^{2\cdot 0 + 1} = 4^1 + 7^1 = 4 + 7 = 11$.  But your induction step needs redoing.

$4^{2(k+1)+1}+7^{2(k+1)+1}=4^{2k+1}4^2+7^{2k+1}7^2=16\left(4^{2k+1}+7^{2k+1}\right)+33\left(7^{2k+1}\right)$ is divisible by $11$

The title and body of the question seem to be asking different things. Here's a potentially 'simpler' way: notice that $7 \equiv -4 \pmod{11}$. Hence, since $2n+1$ is odd,
$$4^{2k+1} + 7^{2k+1} \equiv 4^{2k1} + (-4)^{2k+1}  = 4^{2k+1} + (-1)^{2k+1} 4^{2k+1} = 4^{2k+1} - 4^{2k+1}= 0\pmod{11}.$$
If you want to proceed by induction, you can indeed note that
$$
4^{2(k+1)+1} + 7^{2(k+1)+1} = 4^{2k+3}+7^{2k+3} = 4^2 4^{2k+1} +7^2 7^{2k+1} \equiv 4^2 4^{2k+1} + (-4)^2 7^{2k+1} \pmod{11}
$$
Hence
$$
4^{2(k+1)+1} + 7^{2(k+1)+1} \equiv 16(4^{2k+1}+7^{2k+1}) \equiv 0 \pmod{11};
$$
here we use that $4^{2k+1}+7^{2k+1} \equiv 0 \pmod{11}$ by the inductive hypothesis.

It is potentially helpful if you read the title, though ;) About it being off-topic, I beg to differ. One can adapt the argument to make it fit the induction; see my edit.

OP didn't tell us anything about the nature of the exercise so I did not assume anything about it. You do raise a reasonable point, which is that one should make explicit how that can be linked to the proposed argument, if desired.

It does seem very messy and I'm wondering if there is a smoother way to write this.
You could start from $n=0$ and make explicit use of the induction hypothesis, as below.

Base case: If $n=0$, the result is true because $4^{2\cdot 0+1} + 7^{2 \cdot 0+1}=11$.

Induction hypothesis: Suppose that the result is valid for $k$, that is, there exist $m$ such that
$$4^{2k+1} + 7^{2k+1}=11m\tag{$*$}$$

Inductive step: By the induction hypothesis, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
4^{2(k+1)+1} + 7^{2(k+1)+1}&=4^{2k+1}\cdot 4^2 + 7^{2k+3}\\
&\overset{(*)}{=}(11m-7^{2k+1})\cdot 4^2 + 7^{2k+1}\cdot 7^2\\
&=11m\cdot 4^2+7^{2k+1}(7^2-4^2)\\
&=11m\cdot 16+7^{2k+1}\cdot 33\\
&=11(16 m+3\cdot 7^{2k+1})
 \end{aligned}$$


and this shows that $4^{2(k+1)+1} + 7^{2(k+1)+1}$ is also divisible by $11$.

The result is obvious for $n=0$. For $n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$, use the identity
$$
x^{2n+1}+y^{2n+1}=(x+y)(x^{2n}-x^{2n-1}y+\ldots-xy^{2n-1}+y^{2n}). \tag{1}
$$
If $x=4$ and $y=7$, the RHS of $(1)$ is a multiple of $11$. This completes the proof.
